# CSS - HTML - Space betwwen cells

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want delete this space between these two cells :
[image: Delete this space in fluo]

This is my **[JSFIDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/autxhh02/)**.

I use this CSS class for place my cells. Go to my JSFIDLE, you could see more informations about my code.

```
.border
{
    margin-bottom: -6px;
    margin-left: -6px;
}
```

If you want more informations about my code, tell me!

Comment: Which space are you referring to? The right one or the gap between the cells?

Comment: Add `cellspacing="0"` to `table`

Comment: try this: table { border-spacing: 0; }

Comment: Thanks all. @LuisTeijon I refer to the space on the right of the last cell (just look my screen).

Comment: @NenadVracarIn In CSS or HTML?

Comment: @Pete Thanks but don't work. I want the space on the right of the last cell.

Comment: in HTML ass attribute.

Comment: @NenadVracar Don't work but thanks for your answer.

Comment: @McNavy Sorry, when you said space in between I thought you meant that, not the space at the end.  I think you need to change your layout - html tables are for tabular data only, not layout, and although you do seem to have some tabular data, the fact that you are nesting tables means that something doesn't seem semantically correct.  You may want to think about using rowspans and colspans to remove the nested tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your table class to the following:

```
table
{
width:50px; 
font-size: 13px;
border-spacing: 0px;

}
```

border-spacing allows you to specify the space between your cells

Comment: Work thanks. But this CSS work for it's right for delete the space between each cell.

Comment: Using the chrome devtool, I noticed you have a border-spacing: 2px; defined for your table class in a css file, it is overwriting any modifications you do in the main table or the inner tables. If you disable it, you will be able to specify border-spacing for only the inner tables

Comment: Where did you see border-spacing: 2px ?

Comment: Inspect your table element with the chorme devtool, you can search on the internet how to do so. It is an extremely useful tool for issues like this one.